# When I update value of textbox in plain JavaScript, the text value is invisible

Tags: javascript, html

I just can't see why this function inserts the value of the textbox as invisible. I tried changing the hidden field to a plain visible field, but that didn't help either. Very grateful for enlightenment.
 Here is the full page code, sorry about the german:

```
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background: #111;
            color:      #d00;


        }

        input{
            background: #111;
            color:      #c90;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 7px;

        }


    #aaa{
            top:        10%;
            height:     20%;

            left:       30%;
            width:      40%;

            background: #133;
            color: teal;

            font-weight: bold;

            border: inset 3px #2d2d2d;
            -moz-border-top-left-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-top-left-radius: 20px;   border-top-left-radius: 8px;

             -moz-border-top-right-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-top-right-radius: 20px;   border-top-right-radius: 8px;

              -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;   border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;

              -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;   border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    }       

    #aaa{
            top:        10%;
            height:     20%;

            left:       20%;
            width:      60%;

            background: #333;
            color: #d00;
            padding: 2%;

            font-weight: bold;

            border: outset 3px #2d2d2d;
            -moz-border-top-left-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-top-left-radius: 20px;   border-top-left-radius: 8px;

             -moz-border-top-right-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-top-right-radius: 20px;   border-top-right-radius: 8px;

              -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;   border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;

              -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
             -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
            -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;   border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;

            position: absolute;
    }       
            #geheime{

                visibility: hidden;
            }

            #ang{
                    top:        7%;
                    height:     20%;

                    left:       10%;
                    width:      80%;
                    text-shadow: 2px 2px #111;
                    font-weight: bold;

                    position: absolute;
            }       

            #kaste{
                    top:        30%;
                    height:     20%;

                    left:       10%;
                    width:      80%;

                    font-weight: bold;

                    position: absolute;
            }       

            #fichs{
                    top:        68%;
                    height:     20%;

                    left:       20%;
                    width:      30%;

                    font-weight: bold;

                    position: absolute;
            }       

            #schicks{
                    top:        68%;
                    height:     20%;

                    right:      20%;
                    width:      30%;

                    font-weight: bold;

                    position: absolute;
            }       

    .klKnopfR {
            background:   linear-gradient(to bottom, #f11 0%, #400 100%); /* W3C */

        color:#ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.4em;
                    text-shadow: -1px -1px #411;
             /*-moz-border-top-right-radius:8px;*/
             /*-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;*/
            /*-o-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;   */
            border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .klKnopfG {
        background:   linear-gradient(to bottom, #1f1 0%, #141 100%); /* W3C */
        color:#ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.4em;
                    text-shadow: -1px -1px #141;
             /*-moz-border-top-right-radius:8px;*/
             /*-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;*/
            /*-o-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;   */
            border-radius: 8px;
    }


    .klB {
        background: #4ff; 
        color:#d00; 
    }


</style>
```

```
            <?php
                // include('schaltSatze.php');

                $volleAnreihe = array('hat revealed Einzelheiten von sein balance sheet fuer', '$land tech Einstellung');
            ?>


                <div id="geheime">
                        <?php echo ($volleAnreihe[0]); ?>
                </div><!-- geheime -->


                <div id="ang">
                    <center>
                        <?php echo ($volleAnreihe[0]); ?>
                    </center>
                </div><!-- ang -->


                <div id="kaste">
                    <center>
                        <input type="text" style="color:#c90" id="neuSatz" name="neuSatz" onMouseOver="focus(this)" value="??">
                    </center>
                </div><!-- kaste -->

                <div id="fichs">
                    <center>
                        <input type="button" class="klKnopfR" value="fich's" onClick="stopfSelbe()">
                    </center>
                </div><!-- untwirf -->

                <div id="schicks">
                    <center>
                        <input type="button" class="klKnopfG" value="schick's">
                    </center>
                </div><!-- untwirf -->

</div><!-- aaa -->

<script>
    function stopfSelbe(){

        var e = document.getElementById('geheime');
        var i = e.innerHTML;
        var f = document.getElementById('neuSatz');

        f.value=i;

        alert(i);

        // document.write(i);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It has `visibility: hidden` style

Comment: Could you simplify your [tag:html] in an online demo via [tag:jsbin] or [tag:jsfiddle]

Comment: You mean the text has 'visibility: hidden' style? How would I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty odd that I should end up answering my first ever question on stackoverflow, but in case someone else meets the same problem...

The reason nothing was showing up in the textbox was that the whitespace between the two div tags was being picked up by .innerHTML, and thus numerous tabs/spaces were appearing in the textbox once the obtained value was inserted. And I didn't notice that the alert message was slightly skewed. The actual desired value was there all along, but the textbox was too short for it to be visible.

A better solution would have been

```
            var e = document.getElementById('geheime');
            var i = e.innerHTML.trim();
```